# How to check filesize in HTA VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, hta

I need to check the filesize of a file before reading the file.

I've tried multiple routes with codes I found, it seems I have to look at `.Size` but I can't seem to get it to work any way.

This is the working code so far (if the file has its contents):

```
<script for="battery_parse_1" language="VBScript">
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\core\outputs\vr1_output.log",1)

strBatteryParse1 = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close
Set objFileToRead = Nothing

If InStr(strBatteryParse1, "EstimatedChargeRemaining") Then
    strBatteryParse1Output = Right(strBatteryParse1, 2)
    If strBatteryParse1Output < 10 Then
        strBatteryParse1Output = Right(strBatteryParse1Output, 1)
        1batteryresult.ClassName = "badge bg-red"
        1batteryresult.InnerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-battery-empty'></i> " + strBatteryParse1Output + "%"
    ElseIf strBatteryParse1Output < 25 Then
        1batteryresult.ClassName = "badge bg-red"
        1batteryresult.InnerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-battery-1'></i> " + strBatteryParse1Output + "%"
    ElseIf strBatteryParse1Output < 50 Then
        1batteryresult.ClassName = "badge bg-yellow"
        1batteryresult.InnerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-battery-2'></i> " + strBatteryParse1Output + "%"
    ElseIf strBatteryParse1Output < 75 Then
        1batteryresult.ClassName = "badge bg-yellow"
        1batteryresult.InnerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-battery-3'></i> " + strBatteryParse1Output + "%"
    Else
        1batteryresult.ClassName = "badge bg-green"
        1batteryresult.InnerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-battery-4'></i> " + strBatteryParse1Output + "%"
    End If
    strBatteryParse1Output = strBatteryParse1Output + "% Remaining"
    1batteryresult.Title = strBatteryParse1Output
Else
    strBatteryParse1Output = "No data yet..."
    1batteryresult.Title = strBatteryParse1Output
End If
Set objExec = Nothing
<script>
```

When the remote computer is offline the battery percentage is not logged to the file and it will be empty which makes the string fail ofcourse. It seems whatever code I put in to check if the filesize is 0kb does not work in a HTA.

I have been experimenting with:

```
Set objFile = goFS.GetFile(examplefile)
If objFile.Size > 0 Then
```

but to no success whatsoever.

Edit: Solution is in the comments by Ansgar Wiechers. Hta requires to use

```
Set objFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile
```

instead of

```
Set objFile = goFS.GetFile(examplefile)
```

Comment: Will `strBatteryParse1` be blank in the offline scenario? If it is, you could check that?

Comment: Correct, that is the issue why I'm trying to check for filesize first or add something to the string to avoid it being empty. Sadly nothing seems to work in a hta.

Comment: What I was saying was, instead of checking the filesize, you could check if that string is blank ..

Comment: Ah my bad, I tried that just now with Len but doing it before the strBatteryParse1 = objFileToRead.ReadAll() is useless ofcourse and I cant get passed that line. (sorry very amateur in coding, its a miracle i got so far really).

Comment: `objFile.Size` is the correct way to go about this. Please show code that actually uses it and explain how "no success" manifested iteself exactly, and we may be able to help you improve from there.

Comment: .Size is not recognized as a function in a hta, it does work in a .vbs

Comment: @Rizzah `.Size` is a property of `File` objects (via `FileSystemObject` instances). There is no inherent limitation that prevents using `FileSystemObject` instances in HTAs. Please follow the advice from my previous comment.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers you were right. to get it as a recognized function I needed to use `Set objFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile ` instead of `goFS`

Comment: Assign the `FileSystemObject` instance to a variable, then use that variable: `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") : Set f = fso.GetFile("...")`.